# cordova intent url not working

Tags: cordova, android-intent

In my Cordoba App these links are working:

```
<a href="kakaolink://~~">
<a href="ispmobile://~~">
```

But the following links using the `intent:` prefix won't work.

```
<a href="intent:kakaolink://~~">
<a href="intent:ispmobile://~~">
```

This is my `config.xml`:

```
< Access origin="*"/>
< Allow-intent href="*" />
```

Can you explain why those prefixed urls won't work?